# Pandas logical AND operator giving error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to test a boolean AND condition like below:

```
def test(a,b):
    if(a=='cust' & b=='id'):
        print 0
    else:
        print 1

test('cust','id')
```

I get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: For scalar need `and` like `if(a=='cust' and b=='id')`

Comment: .. because in Python `&` is *exclusively* the [bitwise operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).